# How does Paul Smecker know everyone's name in Boondock Saints?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, boondock-saints

I was rewatching the Boondock Saints recently and noticed that at the start of the film when Willem Dafoe's character is introduced he somehow knows all the names of the cops at the crime scene.

How is that possible? Also, he doesn't know detective Greenley's name which makes it even stranger.

Answer (score 1):

I just rewatched the scene to see if he read their names off their uniforms, but they were all standing way too far away when he addressed them.  The only other explanation that makes sense from what's shown is that Agent Smecker is driven to the crime scene in the back of a marked police car (he's shown arriving at the beginning of the scene, when he flashes his ID to the police chief from the back of the squad car).  He could have met with the uniformed officers at the police station before being taken to the scene, and he almost certainly would have chatted up the two officers that he rode over with.

Answer (score -1):

There's a scene later when he says he has a dossier "on every person in the room". I think the camera cuts imply that means the detectives and police officers, not just the dead Russians.

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies to the question? Care to elaborate?

Comment: This is a quote taken out of context. Smecker says 

"These men are all Russian mob. Not like those two peons in the alley the other day. These guys are all syndicate bosses and underbosses. I have a dossier on every man in this room."

He specifies that he his speaking about the mobsters. Furthermore he also indicates that he did NOT have a dossier for the two original mobsters which is the scene in question.